# how to generate 100 equally spaced numbers drawn from a normal distribution using python

Tags: python-3.x

I generate random numbers using normal distribution in python using **np.random.normal()**

But is there any way to generate **equally spaced numbers** using normal distribution in python?

Comment: Are you asking about generating from the Uniform distribution?  "Equally spaced" doesn't make any sense when pulling random numbers...  Please edit your question for clarity or provide an example of what you expect to generate as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy.linspace() to generate equally spaced numbers in Python.

Below code will generate 50 equally spaced numbers (in x-axis) of a normal distribution with mean 8 and std.deviation 3 covering from 10% to 90% area of normal distribution.

```
    import numpy as np  
    from scipy.stats import norm    
    x = np.linspace(norm(8,3).ppf(0.1), norm(8,3).ppf(0.9), 50)
```

To get the y-axis value of normal distribution for each of the 50 equally spaced x-axis values use below code:

```
    y = norm(8,3).pdf(x)
```

Details of linspace() command:

> numpy.linspace(start, stop, num = 50, endpoint = True, retstep = False, dtype = None)     returns number spaces evenly w.r.t interval

> - start  : [optional] start of interval range. By default start = 0
> - stop   : end of interval range
> - num    : [int, optional] No. of samples to generate
> - restep : if True, return (samples, step). By default restep = False
> - dtype  : type of output array